# Custom List without CreatedBy / ModifiedBy through WebUI/SPD/Javascript

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, content-type

Is it possible to create a truely anonymous list without the created by and modified by columns defaulted, like if someone wanted a suggestion box? Specifically is it possible to do this in SP2010 out of the box web UI, or with SPD, or even using javascript....no server side or managed COM type stuff.

I do not believe this is because if I create a list with JS, I have to select a baseType, and even if I create a cotent type through the web UI I have to have a parent type.....

Just curious if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` fields are internal fields that are included in every list. They talk about this concept here: [Content Types for 'Modified By' and 'Created By'](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e345f075-e346-46e0-8fe9-a75999b7fe89/content-types-for-modified-by-and-created-by)

> “Created By” and “Modified By” are 2 of the internal columns which will be included by all list items in any type of list. Apparently, you can see that the “Created By” and “Modified By” field will not be among the editable columns for any content type. That doesn’t means that the new item created base on these content type will not contain the 2 columns. In fact, content type is not necessary to include the 2 columns, because system will automatically create this kind of internal columns by default. No matter what content type you select to use, when you edit the current view to check on “Created By” and “Modified By”, it will show you the value of these 2 columns, that means they will always company the new item to be generated, and they will never be deleted.

Another approach to an "anonymous" list would be using custom forms and using impersonation of the system token or a designated "anonymous" user to create the list items so the identity in these columns is not the logged in user, but this requires server side code to achieve this.

You can read this to learn about the different impersonation options: [Impersonation in SharePoint: An Extreme Overview](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/30/impersonation-elevation-of-privileges/)

Comment: thanks RJ. you just validated what I thought to be the case but I couldn't seem to find it. appreciated!

Comment: No problem. It's what I'm here for :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggested an SPD approach recently, on a similar question which may help:

[is-there-any-way-to-post-an-anonymous-announcement?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91680/is-there-any-way-to-post-an-anonymous-announcement/91707#91707)

You can just ignore the Approval steps of that solution, the principal is the same. Allow creation, copy the values and then delete it. Then re-create the item entry using the Workflow author account.